GRUB failed to install on apt upgrade
I ran apt upgrade earlier and I just noticed that I'm still in the upgrade, thanks to GRUB failing to install. Any ideas?
This is the error in the console:
grub-install: warning: Cannot delete EFI variable Boot0005.
grub-install: warning: efivarfs_del_variable: unlink failed: Invalid argument.
grub-install: warning: efi_del_variable: ops->del_variable() failed: Invalid argument.
grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Invalid argument.

GRUB error image is shown below.

GRUB window image is shown below.


Are you dual-booting with Windows and perhaps forgot to disable Windows' Fast Startup "feature"?

@ChanganAuto unfortunately no, this is a server.

On your Ubuntu server,Ensure your EFI partition is mounted at /boot/efi. Use lsblk to verify.If it's not mounted, run:
sudo mount /dev/sdX1 /boot/efi

Replace /dev/sdX1 with your EFI partition identifier.After mounting, update GRUB with:
sudo update-grub

Start by reinstalling GRUB
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=GRUB

Use efibootmgr to list existing EFI boot entries and remove any problematic ones with:
sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B

Replace XXXX with the boot number.Check for file system errors on the EFI partition:
sudo fsck /dev/sdX1

Reboot or restart your server

Is this answer A.I. generated?
